# Two phone batteries connected in series not working

Tags: voltage, power, batteries, series, telephone

I have two, fully charged, 3.7V standard Nokia phone batteries, that I want to connect together to use as a 7.4V battery, I connected the (+) of one to the (-) of the other, and then tested it but it does not seem to be working, what am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by you "tested it"? How exactly did you connect them together?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Well I did try soldering them together but I didn't have any experience with that so I resorted to tape, before connecting them I tested each battery individually  by connecting them to a small toy DC motor and they both worked, but I didn't get the same result when I tried again after connecting them together.

Comment: Nokia phone batteries contain electronics. It can clash with your intended usage. I do not know the target that Nokia tried to resist - maybe 3rd party replacement batteries or 3rd party chargers or using the battery without a phone which is purchased from right  area or  some unsafe operating conditions such as short circuit. Try to find what the electronics actually does.

Comment: @user287001 There are no electronics inside phone batteries, it's just layers of Lithium films as you'd expect from a regular Li Ion battery, to answer your question, I'm trying to use the combined battery to power an Arduino Nano board, and a L293D circuit.

Comment: No electronics? That's peculiar. I have believed big companies who have somehow already succeeded to collect some money use everything possible to force people to pay more. If the intention is not to collect more money it's still possible to prevent something dangerous. Check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwslG8S1kYs

Comment: Usually a battery pack contains more than just the bare cells, there is also usually a temperature sensor, a thermal cutoff or fuse, and in some cases back-to-back MOSFET for terminate-charge and terminate-discharge pack protection. For a name-brand company like Nokia, there is a lot of legal liability in letting consumers access a battery pack without charge management and protection. Even the lipo battery packs from Adafruit have this much pack protection. And even bare cells usually have the temperature sensor in close physical contact. It seems very unlikely you have bare Li-ion cells.

Comment: How many terminals on your battery pack? A simple pack with only thermal protection would have three terminals, `+` `-` `T`; while a "smart battery" pack would hare more connections like `+` `-` `T` `C` `D` for SMBus smart battery. Proprietary brands may have other communications schemes. The battery might not give any analog voltage unless it is given a command to enable discharge.

Comment: @user287001 Hmm, the guy in the video you linked removed the top of the battery containing the current limiter, which may I add, looks identical to the ones I have, so I'd like to retract my previous statement and apologize, that might be what I need to do as well...

Comment: @MarkU Three terminals, marked (+)( )(-), I read the middle one indicates "battery state".